# SCP : copy the directory but only with specific files

Tags: scp

I am trying to copy the directory but only with the specific files.

```
sudo scp -r user@ip:'ls /nas1/logs/tomcat/dev-main/dev-main*|grep localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt' /home/test
```

If the files are located like this at remote server,

```
/nas1/logs/tomcat/dev-main/dev-main-1111/localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt    
/nas1/logs/tomcat/dev-main/dev-main-1234/localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt
```

then I want to copy the files like this to the local server.

```
/home/test/dev-main-1111/localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt
/home/test/dev-main-1234/localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt
```

Can I use grep with scp command?

Comment: You can't do that with `scp`. Do you have `rsync` or even `tar` installed?

Comment: 'rsync' is not installed. I have to check it is possible to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `rsync` is not installed per the comment, you can use `tar` instead.

```
ssh user@ip 'cd /nas1/logs/tomcat/ && tar cf - dev-main-*/localhost_access_log.2023-09-22.txt' | tar xf -
```

Explanation:

- `ssh user@ip '...'` executes the command `...` on the remote host
- In this case, the command to be executed is `cd /nas1/logs/tomcat/ && tar cv dev-main-*/localhost_access_log.2023-09-22.txt`, which first changes the remote directory to `/nas1/logs/tomcat/`, then executes `tar` with a glob that matches the files you want to transfer
- The `tar` command, with the `c` option with `f -` for the archive to be dumped on standard output (without the `f` option, it would send it to the default tape device or stdout depending on the `tar` implementation and/or environment) which here is a pipe to the local `tar` command.
- The `tar xf -` part reads the archive from its standard input (the other end of the pipe) and extracts it, preserving the directory structure and some other metadata (add the `p` option to preserve even more metadata).

You should execute the above command in `/home/test/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put commands into an `scp` path, but it looks like you want a set of files that can be matched with a standard glob (wildcard pattern) and there are other tools that will retain the source path.

Here's one:

```
rsync -avR 'user@ip:/nas1/logs/tomcat/./dev-main/dev-main-*/localhost_access_log.2023-09-21.txt' /home/test/
```

Comment: `rsync` is not installed. I have to check the installing.

Comment: Well, actually you can put commands into an `scp` (remote) path, if the protocol is SCP, not SFTP. See "History, SCP and SFTP" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1733992/432690). The point is in case of SCP the path is processed by a shell on the remote side, this is how your (locally single-quoted) `*` works on the remote side in case of SCP; but with SCP `$()` would also work. Not that I recommend using it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski well yes. I've done that in the past with rsync for a very specific situation, but like you I wouldn't recommend it for code that has to be supported by someone else